# How to append multiple elements to a list in Emacs lisp

Tags: list, emacs, elisp

In Emacs lisp there is `add-to-list` to add a single element to a list (if it doesn't exist already).

Instead of one, I want to add multiple elements. Also, I do not want to filter duplicate elements but add them to the list nonetheless.

Currently, I have implemented the following function:

```
(defun append-to-list (list-var elements)
  "Append ELEMENTS to the end of LIST-VAR.

The return value is the new value of LIST-VAR."
  (set list-var (append (symbol-value list-var) elements)))
```

The function does what I want but I was wondering if something like this (or better) already exists in Emacs lisp. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

**Update 1**: Stefan points out below that this code does not work with lexical scoping. Is there a way to make it work?

**Update 2**: Previously I thought that duplicate filtering would be fine but it's not. I do need the duplicates.

Comment: Your code is fine. There is no similar system function.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as "fine", but yes, it will work.  Using `symbol-value` and `set` means it can't be used with a lexically scoped variable.  Unless you **really** need it, better add `elements` at the beginning, since `elements` will almost always be shorter (and sometimes *much* shorter) than `list-var`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the code work with lexical scoping?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be almost equivalent<sup>1</sup> but faster, as it does not make a copy of the original list before appending the new elements.

```el
(defun append-to-list (list-var elements)
  "Append ELEMENTS to the end of LIST-VAR.

The return value is the new value of LIST-VAR."
  (unless (consp elements)
    (error "ELEMENTS must be a list"))
  (let ((list (symbol-value list-var)))
    (if list
        (setcdr (last list) elements)
      (set list-var elements)))
  (symbol-value list-var))
```

<sup>1</sup> `append` does not copy the final element, but uses it directly as the tail of the new list, so that part is identical. However if there are additional references to the original list object (or some part thereof), then there *will* be a functional difference between copying that list (via `append`), and just extending it (with `setcdr`). Which of those two outcomes you actually want is up to you, of course.

Comment: Burps if the original list is nil!

Comment: D'oh. Fixed. Thanks Stefan.

Comment: At least in my current use case I do not keep references around. So this looks cleaner to me because it avoids copying. Thanks! But can it be made to work with lexical scoping?

Comment: No, you can't do this with lexical scoping when the `list-var` argument is a *symbol*, because you've already lost access to the lexical value by doing that.  You would have to pass the list *value* and manipulate that directly.

Answer (score 8):

I have the following in my init file that allows for adding multiple elements.  I don't know how efficient it is to loop through the items to add but it prevents duplicate elements.

```
(defun jlp/add-to-list-multiple (list to-add)
  "Adds multiple items to LIST.
Allows for adding a sequence of items to the same list, rather
than having to call `add-to-list' multiple times."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (item to-add)
    (add-to-list list item)))
```

Comment: This won't work because I actually do need duplicate values in the list.

Comment: If you need duplicates, you can use `push` instead of `add-to-list`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about ordering:

```
(setf var (cl-list* elt1 elt2 elt3 var))
```

The last argument to `list*` becomes the tail of the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) if you want to filter duplicate elements.

```
(setq list1 (-union list1 list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I do this:

```lisp
(setq l `(,@l i1 i2 i3))
```